# Microsoft Graph Access without username?

Tags: graph, microsoft-graph-api

I got a graph link something like this, but longer: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/",

When i open the link i get the following message: InvalidAuthenticationToken.

So my question is, is there a way to access the graph link, without username?

I got Client secret, tenant, client ID and certificate

Hope someone can help me out.

Comment: Which api do you want to call? Do you mean that you want to call the api without user login?

Comment: The client credential flow should work for you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow

Comment: yeah try with client credential flow and see if it works. Outside of your application, you can try with postman as well.